# Rebuilding ipcam video viewer in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket, camera, video-streaming

I have an off-brand ip-camera that displays a live feed of the video in a `<canvas>` element in its web ui. I would like to rebuild this ui.

I believe the camera serves the video feed through a websocket connection since `rtsp://` in not browser compatible. The feed url is: `ws://192.168.0.20:80/websocket`.

I put together a basic browser script that connects to the websocket and listens for messages. It connects fine, but no messages begin streaming. The script looks like this:

```js
const WS_URL = 'ws://192.168.0.20:80/websocket';

function setupWebSocket() {
    const ws = new WebSocket(WS_URL);

    ws.onopen = function() { console.log('connected'); }
    ws.onmessage = function(e) { console.log(e.data); }

    return ws;
}

const ws = setupWebSocket();
```

This code successfully prints "connected" but no messages start arriving in `onmessage`. If I do a `ws.send('some-data')` a message will happily come, but again no video data is being automatically streamed from the camera as I thought it would.

Is it correct to expect video data to automatically begin streaming once connected? If not how would I trigger it to start? Am I going about this correctly? I would appreciate any advice no matter how general. As you can probably tell I am not overly seasoned with sockets or video.

Thanks!

UPDATE: The camera model is [ONWOTE PoE Security Camera UltraHD 4K 8MP with Audio, 2.8mm Lens Wide View Angle, Indoor/Outdoor, 100ft IR, Add on Turret IP Camera to ONWOTE 4K Security System](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B08DFWM3G9?psc=1)

The network panel shows a websocket connection managed by libde265.js which is a library to decode h265 data.

Comment: Most of the IP, PTZ Cameras uses WebSocket connection for controlling network neither serve video over WebSocket.
Could you please give me the brand model of the camera to check?
And please check the network tab of the developer tools of the browser to which protocol uses to update actual canvas image

Comment: The camera model is "ONWOTE PoE Security Camera UltraHD 4K 8MP with Audio, 2.8mm Lens Wide View Angle, Indoor/Outdoor, 100ft IR, Add on Turret IP Camera to ONWOTE 4K Security System": https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B08DFWM3G9?psc=1

The network panel seems to show a websocket connection managed by libde265.js which is a library to decode h265 data.